# How to change what times default to AM/PM in Excel. Willing to use macros

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

In all time formats entering `12:` will return `12:00 PM` for noon. If I wanted midnight I could enter `12:00 a` which is 4 more keystrokes and is ok because I never have a need to track times at night. However this common sense breaks when I enter  `1:` and return `1:00 AM` which is not ok for the same reason.

I'm aware I could use military time or simply change the A to a P. That is my current solution but I see it as a band aid. My intent is to learn how to change what times default to AM or PM passively.

1. Is there a deceptively easy way to tweak the defaults in settings?
2. Is there a VBA/macro solution to this? Again I'm looking for passive change. I don't want to create a hot key to change the second to last character in a string in a given cell to "P". I want that to happen as soon as I hit enter.
3. This one is purely philosophical and would have to be answered by Microsoft employee but somebody at Microsoft had to have suggested that 12 default to noon unlike every other hour. Why didn't they extend this idea to other reasonably afternoon times like noon to 5 or 6?

Comment: curious - how would you prefer entering AM hours, if you ever found the need to do so?

Comment: I scratched my head at this question, as it's only logical (to me, and fans of 24hr notation I suppose) that the first hour of the day should = 1, but I must admit, I'm coming around.  Perhaps a setting to treat single digit numbers from a user-definable range as PM when entering into a time-formatted field isn't a bad idea.  For what it's worth, typing "1 PM" into a time-formatted field works for your use case, so that's just 2 extra keystrokes, but seems harrymc's answer is more what you're looking for.

Comment: I’m running into that question now goof.   Optimally I’d want to type “1: a” on the rare chance I use 1:00 am. If only there was a way to define a variable before  Exc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to tweak the defaults for AM/PM, but there is an easy way to avoid
this problem.

The solution is to enter the date in 24-hours format.

So for "1 PM", just type "13:" and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and it will get immediately
converted to "1:00 PM".

---

The following VBA macro will do what you asked for all values in column 1 (A),
assuming that you never start working before 7 AM:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
    Exit Sub
End If
If Target.Value = "" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

If Target.Column = 1 And Hour(Target.Value) <= 7 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.Value = TimeSerial(Hour(Target.Value) + 12, Minute(Target.Value), Second(Target.Value))
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Harry please read the second paragraph of my answer in where I said I am already using military times and see that solution as a band-aid.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get "military times" - wrong military service, I suppose. Unfortunately, as far as I know, there is no other solution that does not use VBA. Will have a look.

Comment: @harrymc - I think the term 'military time' is a US-only term. Everybody else afaik just uses 12/24 hour clock to differentiate, as you did.

Comment: Second part did it for me thank you Harry

Answer (score 0):

> 1- is there a deceptively easy way to tweak the defaults in settings?

Nope. `12:` gets interpreted as `12:00 PM` because time wraps around at midnight, just like the date does. So `12:` is twelve hours into the day, aka noon. Likewise, `3:` is three hours in, or `3:00 AM`, and `14:` is fourteen hours in, or `2:00 PM`. And the edge cases even work nicely, with both `0:` and `24:` being treated as midnight. Any other interpretation would be mathematically convoluted.

> 2- is there a VBA/macro solution to this? Again I’m looking for passive change. I don’t want to create a hot key to change the second to last character in a string in a given cell to “P”. I want that to happen as soon as I hit enter.

See harrymc's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1459118/766217).

> 3- this one is purely philosophical and would have to be answered by Microsoft employee but somebody at Microsoft had to have suggested that 12 default to noon unlike every other hour. Why didn’t they extend this idea to other reasonably afternoon times like noon to 5 or 6?

Yes, they chose for `12:` to default to noon. Anything else would have had to be coded as a special case. I don't know what you mean by "unlike every other hour". The way they do it is logical and consistent.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to input and display in different cells you could use something like this.

This will work if the time starts in the am and stops within 12 hrs.  Ex

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiR35.png)

in cell d1 put  =TIME(TRUNC(A1/100),MOD(A1,100),)

in cell e1 put =IF(A1>B1,TIME(TRUNC((B1+1200)/100),MOD(B1,100),),TIME(TRUNC(B1/100),MOD(B1,100),))

It could be altered easily if times start after noon and you could put something to override the formula if it switches from starting in am or pm, or if the day should be longer than 12 hrs.

It would work easier than actually typing the colon and am or pm, if there was a common case that happened most frequently.